# Translate an array of NSdictionnary with NSlocalizedstring

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdictionary, nslocalizedstring

I have an array of NSdictionary like this

```
let section1 =
    [NSDictionary(objects: ["English base language test", 2], forKeys: ["title", "value"])
    ]
let section2 =
    [NSDictionary(objects: ["English Base Language test2", 2], forKeys: ["title", "value"])
    ]
```

(I have more objects but for this post i'll just put 1 in the sections)
and so on

Now I want to localize my app but i need to translate the title only

I've tried using `NSlocalizedstring` but i can't fit it in this array

any ideas ??

thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you expect exactly ? if the title is localized why you don't use a key and the NSLocalizedString function to return the correct string ?

Comment: I need to translate the title to French

Comment: Because I want the app to be French and english

Comment: I purpose you an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30326313/1288277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do something like this :

```
let section1 =
    [NSDictionary(objects: [NSLocalizedString("English base language test", comment:""), 2], forKeys: ["title", "value"])
    ]
let section2 =
    [NSDictionary(objects: [NSLocalizedString("English base language test2", comment:""), 2], forKeys: ["title", "value"])
    ]
```

and define two Localizable.strings file, one for french and one for english with this keys :

Localizable.strings (EN)

```
"English base language test" = "English base language test;
"English base language test2" = "English base language test2";
```

Localiable.strings (FR)

```
"English base language test" = "Test d'anglais basique;
"English base language test2" = "Test d'anglais basique 2";
```

Comment: this works if i use only a string, but I also need a value linked to my Nsdictioary (thats why i use it ) like in my examples my value is an Int 2

Comment: oops sorry di'nt see the rest of the answer my bas give me a minute

Comment: Nope that's exactly what I've tried by myself before, I get an error because I need a comment, I add it and then multiple errors show (Add ; this kind of thing which doesn't work)

Comment: Now i'm pretty sure that's run